# How to further optimize android recyclerview?

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview

In the beginning we had listViews. As a developer, we had to recycle and reuse the views to have a fluid experience.

Then, came the recylclerviews. Now, all the recycling heavy lifting is managed by  android library itself.

Using pagination, an infinite recycler view can be implemented, which loads the data when needed.

But there is one problem I am still facing in infinite recyclerview. How is the data in the adapter managed?

In most of the infinite scroll implementations of recyclerview, the new data is appended to the original data. This makes the size of data set ever increasing.
Why cant dataset itself behave like recyclerview and recycle its data, instead of appending? (Like a circular queue).

How can one manage the positions of itemviews, when the dataset is a circular queue. Is it unnecessary and yields too little performance improvement? Am I missing some design pattern?

Comment: If your data is all text, I wouldn't worry about holding it in memory unless you have a really huge number of records, like hundreds of thousands.  If there are images that's a different matter.

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible to clear data already loaded, but this way you have to load data not only for "bottom" views, but for "upper ones" too. So user wants to back to previous data and he needs to load that data again, that's the problem.

There could be more work about notifying data set changed in recyclerView.

You can implement it this way, but remember about pagination and how it is implemented - for example limiting data in SQL statements standard way can output different data each call, so user backing to previous data can see other results! Check [Twitter pagination](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/timelines) for one of the way to achieve same results each time.

Pros:

- less data in memory

Cons:

- more work to write the code
- more data loading for users (more internet usage, more loading times - when users wants back to previous data)
- pagination has to be designed more carefully